# How to make a div appear when clicking on an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an invisible div which I want to make visible by clicking an element.
It doesn't seem to work. What am I missing here?

I've tried targeting `<a class=".demo">` with jQuery and using the click function to add a class `.open` to `<div class="demo-div">` to make it visible

```js
$(".demo").click(function() {
  $(".demo-div").addClass("open");
});

$(".demo").click(function() {
  $(".demo-div").removeClass("open");
});
```

```css
.demo-div {
  background: #3AB0E0;
  color: #18191D;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 3.75rem;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transform: tranlateY(-100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.demo-div.open {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="demo">click here</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="demo-div"></div>
```

And it doesn't seem to add class open to class demo-div

if you delete this class `demo-div` you can see it appear

```
opacity: 0;
visibility: hidden;
```

***Update
I understood what I did wrong, when adding the new class it should contain a closing button such as .demo-close-btn

```
$(".demo").click(function() {
  $(".demo-div").addClass("open");
});

$(".demo-close-btn").click(function() {
  $(".demo-div").removeClass("open");
});
```

Comment: You are adding 2 click handlers to `.demo`. The first adds the class, the second removes it and this happens within milliseconds. Change the second click handler to `$('.demo-div').click()` see https://jsfiddle.net/va6z075d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you've attached two event handlers to the same element, and both of them are conflicting with each other in that they add then remove the class.

To fix this you should use a single event handler and add/remove the class based on its current state. You can do that using `toggleClass()`:

```
$(".demo").click(function() {
  $(".demo-div").toggleClass("open");
});
```

It's worth noting, however that when the `open` class is applied to `.demo-div` the `.demo` element is no longer clickable, as it's occluded. To fix this you could add another click handler to `.demo-div` which removes the `open` class, like this:

```js
$(".demo").click(function() {
  $(".demo-div").addClass("open");
});

$('.demo-div').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.demo-div {
  background: #3AB0E0;
  color: #18191D;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 3.75rem;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transform: tranlateY(-100%);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.demo-div.open {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 99;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="demo">click here</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="demo-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `toggleClass()` instead of add or remove.

```
$(".demo").on('click', function() {
  $(".demo-div").toggleClass("open");
});
```